# Maximum recursion error

Tags: scheme, sicp

Make "if" with "cond"? Why not?

```
(define (new-if predicate if-clause else-clause)
  (cond 
    (predicate if-clause) 
    (else else-clause) ))
```

And next I tried to use it in some function:

```
(define (sqrt x)
    (define (sqrt-iter guess x)
      (new-if 
        (< 
          (abs (- (* guess guess) x)) 
          0.0001 )
        guess
        (sqrt-iter
          (/ (+ guess (/ x guess)) 2)
          x )))
    (sqrt-iter 1. x) )

(sqrt 3)
```

Why I get "maximum recursion depth exceeded"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.  IF and COND don't unconditionally evaluate their arguments, whereas function calls do. `(if #t (display "true") (display "false"))` only prints "true" or "false", but not both.  However, with `(define (my-if condition then else) ...)`, you will always print two things if you do `(my-if #t (display "true") (display "false"))`.